# react-native-router-flux : No React lifecycle method is getting called on back navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, navigator, react-native-router-flux

I am developing a react native app. I am using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) library for navigation in the app.

The library is working fine but while back navigating no react lifecycle method is getting called.

suppose for e.g. I pressed back button on page 2, It gets navigate to page 1 and the componentWillUnmount() of page 2 gets called but **no lifecycle methods of page 1 gets called**.

I want to refresh the page 1 according to new state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code and there are many ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When navigating back, by default `Actions.pop()` is called with no arguments. In order to refresh Page 1, you need to override the functionality of your back button and call `Actions.pop({refresh:{<propsToSetToPage1>}})`. This should trigger `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in Page 1, where nextProps are the new props that you put in the pop().

The following is from react-native-router-flux's documentation:

```
Actions.pop() will pop the current screen. It accepts following optional params:
    {popNum: [number]} allows to pop multiple screens at once
    {refresh: {...propsToSetOnPreviousScene}} allows to refresh the props of the scene that it pops back to
```

PS. If you're developing for Android, you might wanna do this for when the user presses the hardware back button, too. Check [BackAndroid](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.34/docs/backandroid.html) on React Native's official documentation.